# Error getting ESRI Shapefile driver OGR in C++

Tags: gdal, ogr, c++

I am unable to create an OGR Layer using the C++ API. I have followed the documentation at this link exactly http://www.gdal.org/ogr_apitut.html
I get an error trying to get the shapefile driver. Any suggestions?
    const char *driverName = "ESRI Shapefile";
    GDALDriver *pDriver;

```
GDALAllRegister();

pDriver = GetGDALDriverManager()->GetDriverByName(driverName);
if (pDriver == NULL)
{
    qDebug()<<"Error loading driver"; // this error happens
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code works for creating an OGRDataSource. Special thanks to Michael Miles-Stimson for getting me on the right track.

```
const char* path = "C:/Test/test.shp";
OGRRegisterAll();
OGRDataSource *hDS;
OGRSFDriver *driver;
OGRSFDriverRegistrar *registrar =  OGRSFDriverRegistrar::GetRegistrar();
driver = registrar->GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile");
hDS = driver->CreateDataSource(path,NULL);
hDS->CreateLayer("layer",NULL,wkbPoint,NULL);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll use that later when I need to create a shapefile without opening one first.

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to use an OGR (vector) driver with GDAL (raster) tools. Here's a few lines of my working code that may help:

```
char* BasePath = new char[FullPathMax];  // this does have a value before it's used
OGRRegisterAll();
OGRDataSource *hDS = NULL;
OGRSFDriver   *Driver = NULL;
hDS = OGRSFDriverRegistrar::Open(BasePath,FALSE,&Driver);
```

As you can see I don't go making the driver first, it's populated when I open the dataset using the OGRSFDriverRegistrar, that way it could be shapefile or any other OGR format. Calling the GDALAllRegister is fine for GDAL (raster) objects but you need to invoke the OGR equivalent before using OGR objects.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. The information in OGR API Tutorial and the class documentation is not correct. One more question. How would I create a new dataset from a driver instead of opening an existing one? Something like this . . .    OGRSFDriverRegistrar *registrar = OGRSFDriverRegistrar::GetRegistrar();    driver = registrar->GetDriverByName(DriverName);    hDS = driver->CreateDataSource(); ?

Comment: It's not something that I've done but your code looks logical. Try it in debug and see. If it works then answer your own question - I'd vote for it!

Comment: Send a mail to gdal-dev list about wrong information in OGR API Tutorial so they can fix it. It may be because of the recent GDAL/OGR driver unification.

Comment: I don't think it's wrong @user30184, the tutorial that khafen was following was the GDAL tutorial; it was where I started when I learned how to use the GDAL objects, that and the FW_Tools source code (thank you Frank!).

Comment: Probably you are right but it might be good if you as experienced programmer had a look at the API tutorial and think if it reflects the changes introduced by http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/rfc46_gdal_ogr_unification.

Comment: The documentation in for GDAL 2.0, which merges the driver manager of OGR and GDAL.  The 1.x docs can be found here: http://gdal.org/1.11/index.html

Comment: Thank you @kyle, I'll have a look at that. I haven't downloaded GDAL 2.0 yet, but will read that before I do.